# How to echo image inside IF CONDITION using php?

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

I used the following code to echo image. If `slno` is equal to `1` the code will echo to output the image. But if `slno` is greater than `1` (i.e. 2, 3 and so on), the code will just output the `$row['slno']` value...but the code does not produce anything. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php

$image=$row['picture']; //this is the name of the photo i.e. 1.jpg, 2.jpg and so on.
if ($row['slno']=1) //slno holds numerical data 1, 2, 3, 4,
{
  echo '<img width=50 height=50 src="http://localhost/hl/photo/'.$image.'" />';
}
if($row['slno']>1)
{
  echo $row['slno'];
}
?>
```

Comment: `=` is an assignment, `==` is the comparison operator.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a localized typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the value to your variable. You have to compare them:

```
if ($row['slno'] == 1) {
    ...
} else if($row['slno'] > 1) {
    ...
}
```